# Definition of cycle in undirected graph

Tags: graph, theory, graph-theory, cycle

I can't find a formal definition of cycle in an undirected graph. The CLRS only reports a definition of symple cycles that i can't manage to generalize for a generic cycle.

This is the CLRS definition: a symple cycle in a undirected graph is a path `<v0,v1,..,vk>` so that:

1. `k >= 3`
2. `v0 = vk`
3. `v1,..,vk` are distincts

So i tried to remove the `3` condition to define a generic cycle but this can't work because we can have something like this: `<a, b, c, b, a>` that is obviously not a cycle.

Comment: I would add a condition saying that no edge is used more than once. (This is naturally implied when the vertices are distinct, which is why it's not explicitly specified for simple cycles).

Comment: @Henning at a first glance this should work; but my doubt is also if there exist or not a generally accepted definition of this concept, because i can't find it on the internet; i'm studying for an exam so i have to be sure of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can generalize 3 as follows:

1. Either v1,...,vk are distinct *or* they contain a simple cycle (a contiguous list of vertices satisfying 1,2,&3).

Answer (score 0):

Path in graph theory means list of edges or/and vertices satisfying some connectivity conditions. Cycle is closed path, first and last list element are same. [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_%28graph_theory%29)

Path or cycle is called simple if there are no repeated vertices or edges other than the starting and ending vertices. Your example is cycle, but not simple cycle.